# ffmpeg select filter starting time?

Tags: ffmpeg, video-processing

I am stuck with ffmpeg select filter.

I am trying to generate 10 thumbnails from the video and it works fine.

However, I want to skip some starting time (around 30 seconds), since there are usually video intros, etc.

So I can't figure out a way to do that - not using ffmpeg too often.
The command I'm currently using:

```
ffmpeg -loglevel panic -y -i "test.mp4" -frames 1 -q:v 1 -vf "select=not(mod(n\,7877)),scale=-1:227,tile=10x1" video_preview.jpg
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `-ss hh:mm:ss` flag in your command to move the seek to a particular instance in the video.

Command will look something of the sort

```
ffmpeg -ss 00:00:30 -loglevel panic -y -i "test.mp4" -frames 1 -q:v 1 -vf "select=not(mod(n\,7877)),scale=-1:227,tile=10x1" video_preview.jpg
```

Comment: Thanks! I tried that before but it seems like it should be the first argument in order to work, missed that.